# What are the options for forcing a scrollbar in an Android webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am building a webview for an Android app.

For desktop browsers, I can add `overflow-y: scroll` on the `<body>` tag to force a scrollbar track onto the page, but this does not force an actual scrollbar.

I'm being asked to "force a scrollbar" in the app, but I'm concerned it will do just that, put a track in place but not the actual scrollbar.

Is there a way to force the scrollbar to be visible no matter what version of Android the webview is loaded into?

What are the options on the Android side and on the HTML+CSS side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now the best way is to use `android:fadeScrollbars="false"` in xml which is equivalent to `ScrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);` in java code.

or

Setting the `android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"` will do the trick.

**Eg:** in your onCreate() method : try this :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_web_view_layout); 

    browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.your_webview);
    WebSettings mWebSettings = browser.getSettings();
    mWebSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    browser.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    browser.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}
```

**OR**

Try using `WebView` inside a `ScrollView` and use `android:fadeScrollbars="false"` for the `ScrollView`

**Eg:**

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="86px" 
            android:id="@+id/scrollTxtDescription"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtLieuPromo1" 
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/txtLieuPromo1">

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/layoutTxtDescription"
                >

                <WebView android:id="@+id/txtDescription" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

In your code you can try this:

```
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

This will disable the scrollbars from fading away.

Answer (score 1):

Just Add these lines in your activity to the webview, and no need to add anything in xml,this will lead both horizontal and vertical scroll.

```
     webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

                    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                    webview.loadData("Your Content to show in the webview,
                            "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

try with this code, hope you will get the solution.